# "[SpyderKernelApp] WARNING | No such comm:" bm3d error in python trough spyder in a mac

Tags: python, macos, kernel, spyder, noise-reduction

I recently installed bm3d noise reduction algorithm on my mac by typing

```
pip install bm3d
```

on the terminal.

Everything seemed ok.

However, every time I try to run it I get the same error

```
[SpyderKernelApp] WARNING | No such comm:
```

followed by a Hex number such as in

```
[SpyderKernelApp] WARNING | No such comm: 74d9826ed0f911ea817428cfe91fcdb3
```

or in

```
[SpyderKernelApp] WARNING | No such comm: 4a205fd8d0fa11ea817428cfe91fcdb3
```

.

I'm running a pretty simple code such as

```
from bm3d import bm3d
import numpy as np
bm3d(np.random.rand(100,100),100)
```

.

The error seems to have nothing to do with bm3d.

I'm running Python 3.8 trough Spyder 4.1.4 in macOS Mojave 10.14.6.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) The error means that your code crashes the IPython console. If you installed Spyder with Anaconda, that's probably the cause. Please see [our video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ul79ihg41Rs) on the reasons why you must not mix pip and conda packages.